# Creating nested json for hotel system

Tags: php, json

I want to create a nested json that comes with post.
I have 3 fields. Adults, children and baby. But, there are also dates for children and baby areas. For example; Children 1 Birthday, Children 2 Birthday, Baby 1 Birthday, Baby 2 Birthday
When I try with the code below, I can't print child dates by room. Writes in bulk. How can I POST with php like json below?

```
 +---------+----------+-------+
 | Adults  | Children | Baby  | (select box field)
 +--------------------+--------
 | 1       | 0        | 0     |
 +--------------------+--------
 | 2       | 1        | 1     | (also available for children and baby areas)
 +--------------------+-------+
 | 3       | 2        | 2     |
 +---------+----------+-------+

rooms: [
         {
            adults: 2,
            child: [
               child_total: 1
               child_date: [
                   "2017-08-10"
               ],
            ],
            baby: [
               baby_total: 1
               baby_date: [
                   "2017-07-01"
               ],
            ],
         },
         {
            adults: 1,
            child: [
               child_total: 2
               child_date: [
                   "2017-08-08",
                   "2017-08-09"
               ],
            ],
            baby: [
               baby_total: 2
               baby_date: [
                   "2017-06-08",
                   "2017-05-09"
               ],
            ],
         }
      ],

        foreach ($this->input->post('adults') as $key => $value) {

            foreach ($_POST['child_total'] as $value2) {
                $child_date = [];
                foreach ($_POST['child_date'] as $key2 => $value3) {
                    $child_date[] = $value3;
                }
            }

            $rooms[] = array(
                'adults' => $_POST['adults'][$key],
                'child' => array(
                    'child_total' => $_POST['child_total'][$key],
                    'child_date' => $child_date
                )
            );
        }
        print json_encode($rooms, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: It seems that you are adding baby and child as arrays. Maybe you should change [ ] for { } and add a comma after child_total and baby_total

Comment: The first issue is how are you receiving the data. Is it through an html form?  Do you know how to name the variables in the html inputs?  How many rooms are you trying to enter at a time (one would be better for simplicity)? How many children and babies are allowed per room?  Until you answer these questions, the foreach loop working with the $_POST data is impossible to know.  I still have no idea why you are json encoding nor what you hope to accomplish with that. Json encoding is typically for making an Ajax response to the post.